# Vb.net Select data from ListView and Post every data to label

Tags: vb.net

How do i post the selected row in my listview to my label?

```
 Private Sub listview_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles listRecentTransactions.SelectedIndexChanged

        If listview.SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
            Label16.Text = listview.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(1).Text
            Label17.Text = listview.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(2).Text
            Label18.Text = listview.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(3).Text
            Label19.Text = listview.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(4).Text
            Label20.Text = listview.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(5).Text
            Label21.Text = listview.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(6).Text
        End If
    End Sub
```

ListView

[image]

Comment: You didn't say what is going wrong.  `listRecentTransactions` is not the same thing as `listview`.  Guessing you should start SubItems at zero: `SubItems(0).Text`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `MouseClick` event to your ListView. Go to the properties of your ListView, click the thunder icon, find `MouseClick`, and double click the field.

[image]

Then paste your code

```
Private Sub ListView1_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles ListView1.MouseClick
    Label16.Text = ListView.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(1).Text
    Label17.Text = ListView.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(2).Text
    Label18.Text = ListView.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(3).Text
    Label19.Text = ListView.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(4).Text
    Label20.Text = ListView.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(5).Text
    Label21.Text = ListView.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(6).Text
End Sub
```